# jQuery UI Button doesn't work on IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$path?>common/_LIB/3rd/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$path?>common/_LIB/3rd/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="<?=$path?>common/_LIB/3rd/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    $(function() {
            $('.button,.button floatRight').button();
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<a class="button floatRight" href="handset_list.php"><?=$reprint?></a>
```

and all is well on Chrome and FF, IE 9, but on IE 8 and IE 7, I can't see the button for the above link only.

Comment: What does the console say, actually?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code in jQuery selector. There is no tag name called **"floatRight"**.
Try this:

```
$('.button').button();
```

Comment: make sure your custom jQuery UI build contains Button widget

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
$(function() {
        $('.button,.button floatRight').button();
});
```

A space in the tag attribute means there are two classes. In your case the button you try to target has two classes: `button` and `floatRight`. Hence two dots.

**EDIT:**
I found something else: the function `$("#something").button();` calls `$.data` a lot of times. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) IE only has partial support for custom data on attributes, So, it may not work as the jQuery UI developers think it would in IE 7. The many calls to `$.data` make me think the `.button()` function kind of relies on it (but I don't really understand it yet, I just had a quick glance). If that is so, that is probably the cause. If you really need IE 7 support I suggest using a jQuery UI build released when IE 7 was the most used IE, although that might not support all features you use now. I'd say just let IE 7 users see an anchor. What's so bad about an anchor?